# how to replace an apostrophe using gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to replace apostrophe(') in a name with "backslash apostrophe" (\') . But Unfortunately not getting such a simple thing.

So on irb I tried following

x = "stack's"
x.gsub(/[\']/,"\'")

Some how it is not working I am getting same result- stack's in place of stack\'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
x.gsub(/[']/,"\\\\\'")
```

Result:

```
1.9.3p0 :014 > puts x.gsub(/[']/,"\\\\\'")
anupam\'s
```

Comment: 1.8.7-p357 :008 > x.gsub(/[']/,"\\\\'")
 => "anupam\\'s"


I am getting this :(

Comment: That's normal - inspect produces escaped output. if you call puts on the output then you won't see the extra backslash

Comment: I think you 'only' need 4 slashes if you are using a double-quoted string. You'd need 5 for a single-quoted string. See [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179618).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
x = "anupam's"; puts x.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

Comment: i am getting output as "anupam\\'s" :(

Comment: I actually want to put this string in java script(to form a url) ... so will this anupam\\'s string work

Comment: as mentioned in other comments, the output (in, e.g., irb) gets escaped too. if you use puts to print it out, there won't be two backslashes on the screen. and then you can use it in java.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ruby variant for PHPs addslashes method (from http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/113067#263640). This method also escapes `\` in the string, with double `\`:

```
class String
  def addslashes
    self.gsub(/['"\\\x0]/,'\\\\\0')
  end
end
```

Which would correctly escape anupam's:

```
"anupam's".addslashes # => "anupam\\'s"
```

Comment: I actually want to put this string in java script(to form a url) ... so will this anupam\\'s string work

Comment: there's a helper for that in rails... `escape_javascript` or... just use `"anupam's".to_json` :)